# Negative loop gain of LDO

Tags: ltspice, ldo, stability, bode-plot, loop-gain

I am trying to design an LDO with the following specification: Vout = 1.5V; Vin = 1.7V - 2V; Iload = 75uA to 1200uA. However, while I am simulating its loop gain, its gain is coming negative. Even though all the transistors are in saturation within the given load condition. I have attached the testbench as well as the Bode Plot for it. Can anybody suggest what might be the reason?[image: Testbench for AC analysis][image: Output of AC analysis]

Comment: That's not a negative gain, it means your output AC signal is less than 1V. Gain is a ratio. Please add the plot of V(out)/V(in)

Comment: Your schm is a bit poorly drawn, but from what I can see, there's no negative feedback. It don't see the middle point of your R1 and R2 network connected to either input of your amplifier.